# Rendering if statement depending upon what state is in React web app

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to render a span containing different text depending upon the current state.

I figured this should be straightforward, but it's not proving to be..

I have four variables:

```
const stNumbers = [1, 21, 31]
const ndNumbers = [2, 22]
const rdNumbers = [3, 23]
const thNumbers = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

Each of these is an array of numbers from 1 to 31. The array they're in depends upon how they are shown in a date, i.e. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc.

I then have a function, which depending upon the state renders a span based on whether the state matches any of the values in the above arrays.

```
const numbersCheck = () => {
      if (stNumbers.includes(this.state.paymentDate)) {
        return <span>st</span>
      } else if (ndNumbers.includes(this.state.paymentDate)) {
        return <span>nd</span>
      } else if (rdNumbers.includes(this.state.paymentDate)) {
        return <span>rd</span>
      } else if (thNumbers.includes(this.state.paymentDate)) {
        return <span>th</span>
      } else {
        return <span></span>
      }
    }
```

This calls 'includes' to check through each of the arrays and figure out which span it should render.

I then want to render this function inside my component so rather than their being just a number, i.e. 3, 9, 12, 24 or any other example, it instead says 3rd, 9th, 12th, 24th.

The input sets the state upon text entry.

I'm attempting to do this like so:

```
<div className="link-debt-input-container">
              <input className="link-debt-number-input" list="date-list" name="paymentDate" value={this.state.paymentDate} onChange={this.onChange} />
                <datalist id="date-list">
                  <option value="1" />
                  <option value="2" />
                  <option value="3" />
                  <option value="4" />
                  <option value="5" />
                  <option value="6" />
                  <option value="7" />
                  <option value="8" />
                  <option value="9" />
                  <option value="10" />
                  <option value="11" />
                  <option value="12" />
                  <option value="13" />
                  <option value="14" />
                  <option value="15" />
                  <option value="16" />
                  <option value="17" />
                  <option value="18" />
                  <option value="19" />
                  <option value="20" />
                  <option value="21" />
                  <option value="22" />
                  <option value="23" />
                  <option value="24" />
                  <option value="25" />
                  <option value="26" />
                  <option value="27" />
                  <option value="28" />
                  <option value="29" />
                  <option value="30" />
                  <option value="31" />
                </datalist>
              { numbersCheck }
            </div>
```

Every time I try to render my page though, I get the following error:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if
> you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe
> you meant to call this function rather than return it.

I don't understand how this is happening though, as I am returning the spans inside the 'numbersCheck' function?

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the method instead of just inserting it:

```
{ numbersCheck() }
```

JSX builds up a tree of React elements. You are trying to insert a function instead of an element into the tree.

Comment: Thanks - that takes away the error, but doesn't render anything in my page. So I'm assuming it's calling it upon page load (componentDidMount) but not updating based on the state of my input?

Comment: The function will be called again when the props/state of this component change. I assume nothing is rendered because you are entering the else block with the empty span?

Comment: You could try to debug this with the dev tools if you are unsure what is happening. cheers